# What short movie was about humans having a 7-day lifespan?

Tags: movie, story-identification

I've seen this short movie when I was a kid, but I don't remember the title. The story is that humans live underground, and have a lifespan of seven days.

They train a newborn on his first day and send him on a quest to open some door that will lift the curse.
On his way he battles with some monsters, plays some kind of chess with some other monster, and on the seventh day opens the door.

I remember that the short movie had animatronics, and even some CGI (this was around the late '80-ties, I think), but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie you reference, but there is an episode of Stargate: SG-1 that deals with humans who have a 100 day lifespan.  It may have been inspired by the same work, in part.

Comment: Sounds like it's an adaptation of Bradburys "Frost and Fire" ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Could it possibly be [Quest (1984)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086162/)?

> On a distant planet, descendants of a crashed spaceship are subjected
>   to mysterious forces that cause them to age and die in just eight
>   days..

Comment: [Don't you mean 1996](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quest_%281996_film%29)?

Comment: No, I mean the one I'm linking to ;)

Comment: Strange that two unrelated films would sound so similar.

Comment: That's the one! Tnx. Any way to obtain this short?

Answer (score 10):

I haven't heard of a movie that fits all your details, but the plot sounds a lot like Ray Bradbury's short story "Frost and Fire".

Comment: Excellent story, as well as the basis for the movie.

Answer (score 6):

**Caution Dr. Who Spoilers:**

The Dr. Who episode "[The Doctors Daughter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_Daughter)" plays with the concept of short lifespans. The entire history and mythology of the clones in that episode takes place over the course of 7 Days.

Answer (score 6):

Ray Bradbury's short story was actually the basis for the short movie "Quest" (1983)--I found the film on YouTube--here's the links (it's in two parts):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0v9CrmEpT8

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=st64go_iXnk&feature=related

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of a particular film either, but there's an episode in Stargate: SG-1 where an alien scientist has altered the metabolism of an isolated pocket of human beings such that their lifespan is on the order of a hundred days. Not quite the seven, but still.