# Identify a movie with a tribe of children, with one on a quest

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to find the title of a film I watched in high school.
The premise was a tribe(?) of people, and each person's entire life span was either 7 or 14 days (I cannot recall which). Each child began training basically as soon as they were born.
There was a young boy who was being trained to be a warrior as his purpose was to go on a quest. I recall there was a structure in the distance that they could see, and it was this that they believed held the secret to their existence.

Comment: When were you in high school (what time frame did you watch this)? Was it live-action or animated? Was it in English? Was it in color? Did it seem geared towards any age group? Do you have any recollections of names of characters or actors? Any details you may remember may help us find this for you.

Comment: Is it the same movie that [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2135/what-short-movie-was-about-humans-having-a-7-day-lifespan) is asking about? If so, the answer seems to be [*Quest*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086162/), based on the short story ["Frost and Fire"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_(short_story)) by Ray Bradbury.